# Nightwatch: How to run certain tests in parallel and others in sequential

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have segregated all tests in folders based on the features in the app. There are some tests that do some settings in the app before actual testing happens. Such tests can't run in parallel otherwise expected settings might not be there. The requirement is to execute such tests in sequence. What could be the solution? Thanks in advance